# Can somebody tell me why my "thumbnails" aren't in the row format I am attempting in code link?

Tags: html

Can somebody tell me why my "thumbnails" (will make them look nicer after setting up the page) are not in the row format I am attempting in [code link](http://codepen.io/gusd773/pen/ryYXqe/)?

```
<div class="row">
      <div class= "col-md-6">
           <div class="thumbnail">
               <a target="_blank" href="http://codepen.io/gusd773/pen/YZExVE">
               <img src="http://jumpoff.tv/assets/images/made/assets/images/posts/ready_to_die2_326_202_s_c1_center_top.jpg"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class= "col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <a target="_blank" href="http://codepen.io/gusd773/pen/YZExVE">
                 <img src="http://jumpoff.tv/assets/images/made/assets/images/posts/ready_to_die2_326_202_s_c1_center_top.jpg"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are CSS in the codepen for

```
`col-md-6`
```

Use the below code and adjust the width for columns.

```
`.col-md-6{width:50%; float:left;}`
```

Let me know one if that works the way you intended it to.

Comment: YES thank you a ton!! Now when you say (for clarification purposes) "There are CSS in the codepen for _____" in this case the class 'col-md-6', what do you mean? my code works now tho just want to make sure I understand the lingo as I'm new to css html etc.

Comment: What I meant was you have used the class (`col-md-6`) in your code `<div class= "col-md-6">` (in CodePen - HTML line 18) but there is no CSS associated for it. 
Did my code fix the issue or the Bootstrap option? If mine did, please choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: Gotcha just dapped you up w a green check bro, preciate it.

Comment: Thank you for that. If you need to contact me, look for 'syfer does web'.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not referencing bootstrap

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpXBRJ)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```